# How to make ZXing shown in part of activity (not full screen) in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using **ZXing** for barcode scanning, but it show the scanner as a full screen (**picture 1**), but I want to show the scanner as part of my activity (**picture 2**).

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

[image]

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for. [ContinuousCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)

Comment: Exactly, I am very thankful for you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful for you. I will write that as an answer, so that you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ContinuousCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) to achieve what you are looking for.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Please, try to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141833/how-to-make-the-zxing-scan-using-the-front-camera-not-the-back-camera-in-android , it is related to the same current question.