# How to make the ZXing scan using the front camera not the back camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using the **ZXing** by the following code [ContinuousCaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java), and the zxing using (by default) the **back** camera to scan, how to make it scan using the **front** camera ?

Answer (score 1):

set extra SCAN_CAMERA_ID to the ID of the camera you want

usually 1 for the front one.

for example

```
 intent.putExtra("SCAN_CAMERA_ID", 1);
```

Comment: I am not using your method to initiate the scanner, how to make that in this code https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java